# using Scrapy fetch command to auto write the seen html to a file?

Tags: scrapy

I'm in my early days of learning scrapy. At the moment when I start to work with a new page I will go to the cmd prompt and enter for example

```
scrapy fetch https://www.bbc.co.uk
```

It will immediately show the full html of that page in the cmd box. I am then manually highlighting, copying and pasting that html into notepad to check the information I will want to scrape for is there as i've found some sites cannot be seen fully by scrapy.

There must be an easier method than manually copying and pasting into notepad. Is there a command modifier I could add to the fetch command to get it to save the html to a file?

Answer (score 0):

`scrapy fetch --nolog https://www.bbc.co.uk > response.html`

Answer (score 0):

Got a fast enough fix, here it is;

```
scrapy shell url
```

then

```
view(response)
```

will show what scrapy sees by displaying that in your browser. Can view html from there if needed.